# display user geo location in html page

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, geolocation

i am new to html5 and using cordova and has the code as below. once i use the html5 geo location object i need to display the value in the user current screen.The code is as below

```
function onDeviceReady() {
            // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
            // device.
            var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
            watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        }
        // onSuccess Geolocation       
        function onSuccess(position) {
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
            element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' +
                            '<hr />' + element.innerHTML;



}

                            document.write=(element);

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <p id="geolocation"need to display user geo location here </p>



</body>
```

Comment: And your code doesn't work? What das onError give you out?

Comment: my code is working , but i want to show the collected values from the above code from device on the screen , something like printf / document.write(latitude,lungitude)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code:

```
<p id="geolocation">your coordinates:</p>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("geolocation");
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML+="<br>Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
```